# Difference in sorting (Order By) for Date Fields in EntityFramework vs Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework

When the below two queries executed, there is a difference in the result sorting order for the users with exactly same CreatedTime.

Oracle Query Results

```
Select UserName, CreatedTime from TableA 
where CreatedTime > '01-Jan-2014' order by CreatedTime;

User1   12/13/2014 12:38:58 PM
User2   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User3   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User4   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User5   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
```

LINQ Results

```
 using (var dbContext = new MyDBEntities())
 {
        var users = from x in dbContext.TableA
                    where
                    x.CreatedTime > JanFirst2014
                    orderby x.CreatedTime
                    select user;
 }

User1   12/13/2014 12:38:58 PM
User3   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User2   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User5   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
User4   12/23/2014 12:38:58 PM
```

We can fix this issue by ordering by UserName, But what is the reason for this issue/difference?

Comment: The date values are the same. SQL does not guarantee any order for items that compare equally. You must specify another `orderby` clause to additionally order by another column which the original query looks to be doing.

Comment: That said, please post the SQL code being generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: Use `String sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();` to get the generated SQL.

Comment: Maybe the precision of dates in .Net is different to Oracle?

Comment: @Dai Tried executing SQL code generated from Entity Framework, results are matching with that of Oracle Results.